# Django ORM - How to access annotated field value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Let's assume I have the next models:

```
class A(model):
    b = models.ManyToManyField("b", through="AB")

class B(model):
    id = models.CharField()

class AB(model):
     a = models.ForeignKey("a")
     b = models.ForeignKey("b")
```

I want to retrieve all related A objects for specific B object and plus annotated field `count_something` for each A object.

```
b_obj = B.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('ab_set',  
                                   queryset=AB.objects.select_related('a')
                                              .annotate(count_something = Count(....))))
                .get(id=<b_id>)
```

I've tried this way, but it does not work

```
a_qs = [ab.a for ab in b_obj.ab_set.all()]

for a in a_qs:
    print(a.count_something)
```

error:

```
 "A" object has no attribute 'count_something'
```

What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

This is not annotated on the `a` objects, but the `AB` objects, so:

```
for ab in b_obj.ab_set.all():
    print(ab.count_something)
```

Comment: Thank you. So is it not possible to annotate  "select_related" model ?

Comment: @JeremyBearimy: no, it is always on the model you annotate.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `"@property"` to the A model,like

```py
class A(model):
    b = models.ManyToManyField("b", through="AB")

    @property
    def count_something(self):
        # do your count
        pass
```

then use your way again

```py
a_qs = [ab.a for ab in b_obj.ab_set.all()]

for a in a_qs:
    print(a.count_something)
```